# How to put two elements next to eachother?

Tags: css

***HTML:***

```
<div class="epBtn">
    <span class="thumbnail">
        <img src="episodes/1.jpg" />
    </span>
    <span class="play">Episode 1</span>
</div>
```

What can I do, CSS-wise, to make `.thumbnail` and `.play` appear next to each other without using `float`?

Comment: Next time please format your code as code - and indent - so we can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Also, what have you tried that did not work?

Comment: Add CSS Property: `display: inline-block`

Comment: Do you have any proof that they **don't** show up next to each other? As far as I can tell, they are side-by-side in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XCyQP/

Comment: Do you have any css already accompanying that html snippet? like something that might apply to the epBtn class?

Comment: Updated my answer. try once..

Answer (score 0):

**Use `inline-block`:**

```
<div class="epBtn">
    <span class="thumbnail">
        <img src="episodes/1.jpg" />
    </span>
    <span class="play">Episode 1</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.thumbnail, .play { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Comment: I tried out his code in a jsfiddle and they already appear to be next to each other.. http://jsfiddle.net/XCyQP/

Answer (score 0):

I have modeled what I believe you are trying to accomplish at the address below. It is accomplished by setting the area for the thumbnail (the left in this case) as margin space in the container, then absolutely positioning the thumb to center within the that container. Since the height of the container is generally known (via the thumb) you can then center the relative content vertically using the `top` css property. Since the container is also position relative the absolutely positioned contents will be absolute to it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAEGm/1/)

```
.epBtn {
    /* These are cosmetic except for height, which you should know. */
    max-width: 170px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: relative;
    font-family: arial;
}
.play {
    top: 20px;
    margin-left: 65px;
    position:relative;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 5px;
}
```

Please let me know if this what you had in mind.